# control seq for errors in unnamed pipe

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

```
$ awk -v f=<(cmdmayfail) -e 'BEGIN { r = getline < f ; print r }'
-bash: cmdmayfail: command not found
0
```

In the above-unnamed pipe example, `awk` will not know the error from the unnamed pipe.

```
$ awk -v f=<(cmdmayfail || echo "control sequence" ) -e 'BEGIN { r = getline < f ; print r }'
```

To make `awk` aware of this error, I could use the above code by sending a control sequence and some error info.

Given that `file` already knows many file types, is there reasonable control sequence that can be used for this application so that `awk` will not mistreat the error control sequence as from a legitimate file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your `commandmayfail` is a standard Unix command, preceding the controlsequence with your own complex text (for example `__ERROR__CMDFAIL__:`) should be sufficient to let `awk` understand the difference.

However, if you also include your own and/or propriety software, it is hard to give you a general string. It is possible (though unlikely) that one of your propriety commands uses such a string. You should look at the general setup of the error messages and create a string that is unlikely to be used.

If the `commandmayfail` is `file`, as the question suggests, it may be sufficient to use a string without `:`.

Answer (score 0):

If the output from `cmdmayfail` is relatively small and the command itself terminates independently from other parts of your code, then you can store its output in a variable and pass the exit status as the very first line. The code in `<()` would be like:

```
out="$(cmdmayfail)"; printf '%s\n' "$?" "$out"
```

Your `awk` should `getline<f` to get the exit status. Consecutive `getline<f` will read the actual output of `cmdmayfail`.

Limitations:

- Variables in Bash cannot store null characters.
- `$()` will strip all trailing newline characters; then `printf` will add exactly one. A cumbersome trick to avoid this:

  ```
  out="$(cmdmayfail; s="$?"; printf X; exit "$s")"; printf '%s\n%s' "$?" "${out%X}"
  ```

The fact you handle the output from `cmdmayfail` in the `BEGIN` block may indicate you expect `cmdmayfail` to terminate early. Maybe this solution will be enough.

---

In general `cmdmayfail` may even run "endlessly" (i.e. until you terminate it) and you may want to read from its output while processing the ("endless") stdin of `awk`. In such case the above solution will not work.

You can prepend each line of the output from `cmdmayfail` with some fixed status line (e.g. `OK`) and finally add a line with the exit status of `cmdmayfail`. The code in `<()` would be like:

```
 cmdmayfail | sed 's/^/OK\n/'; printf '%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

Example:

```
$ (printf '%s\n' foo "bar baz"; exit 7) | sed 's/^/OK\n/'; printf '%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
OK
foo
OK
bar baz
7
```

Then your `awk` code should `getline<f` and check if it's `OK`. If so, the next line (`getline<f` again) is from `cmdmayfail` for sure. Loop to parse all lines until there is no `OK` when you expect it. Then it's the exit status.

This will work fine unless `cmdmayfail` may generate an [incomplete line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195). Example:

```
$ (printf 'foo\nincomplete line'; exit 22) | sed 's/^/OK\n/'; printf '%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

Depending on the implementation of `sed`, the tool may

1. ignore the incomplete line at all, or
2. process it and add the missing newline character, or
3. process it as-is.

In effect you will

1. miss some part of the output, or
2. not know the line was incomplete, or
3. get the line with the exit status attached to it.

In case of (3) `printf '\n%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"` may help. It will generate an extra empty line if the last line from `cmdmayfail` is complete; this way your `awk` code will be able to tell.

Consider a case when `cmdmayfail` was forcefully terminated mid-line. You may not want to parse the incomplete line then. The problem is: to know in `awk` whether the line form `cmdmayfail` was complete or not you need to test the next (status) line. Implementing useful logic for this in `awk` may be at least inconvenient.

---

It's good to detect an incomplete line as soon as possible, [`read` in Bash can do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482525/108618). The downside is `read` is slow (and remember Bash variables cannot store null characters). Example solution:

```
# define this helper function in the main shell
encerr () { ( eval "$@" ) | (while IFS= read -r line; do printf 'C\n%s\n' "$line"; done; [ -n "$line" ] && printf 'I\n%s\n' "$line") ; printf 'E\n%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"; }
# this part you want to put in <()
encerr cmdmayfail
```

Then you need to decode the custom protocol inside `awk`. Lines go in pairs. (See the examples down below to understand the protocol more intuitively.)

1. Read the first line from a pair (`getline<f`).
2. Store the first line in a variable (`first=$0`).
3. Read the second line from a pair (`getline<f`).
4. Analyze the first line (`$first`).

   - If it's `C` then the second one (current `$0`) is a complete line from `cmdmayfail`, you can parse it.
   - If it's `I` then the second one is an incomplete line from `cmdmayfail`, you may or may not want to parse it. Expect `E` in the next pair.
   - If it's `E` then the second one is the exit status from `cmdmayfail`. You should not expect further pairs.
5. Loop.

Note I used `eval "$@"` inside the function. What you write after `encerr` will be evaluated for the second time, so usually you would like to run something like

```
encerr 'cmd1 -opt foo'
```

or

```
encerr "cmd1 -opt foo"
```

or even

```
encerr 'cmd1 -opt foo | cmd2'
```

Basically this is the form you use to run remote commands with `ssh`. Compare:

```
ssh a@b 'cmd1 -opt foo | cmd2'
```

Or you can build the function like this:

```
encerr () { "$@" | …
```

and call it like this:

```
encerr cmd1 -opt foo
```

Compare to `sudo`:

```
sudo cmd1 -opt foo
```

Examples (using the original function with `eval`):

- success with empty output

  ```
  $ encerr true
  E
  0
  ```
- failure with empty output

  ```
  $ # I'm redirecting stderr so "command not found" doesn't obfuscate the example
  $ encerr nonexisting-command-foo1231234 2>/dev/null
  E
  127
  ```
- success after complete lines

  ```
  $ encerr 'date; sleep 1; date'
  C
  Mon Sep 30 09:07:40 CEST 2019
  C
  Mon Sep 30 09:07:41 CEST 2019
  E
  0
  ```
- failure after complete lines

  ```
  $ encerr 'printf "foo\nbar\n"; false'
  C
  foo
  C
  bar
  E
  1
  ```
- success after an incomplete line

  ```
  $ encerr 'printf "foo bar\n89 baz"'
  C
  foo bar
  I
  89 baz
  E
  0
  ```
- failure after an incomplete line

  ```
  $ encerr 'printf "\nThe first line was empty and this one was interru"; exit 33'
  C

  I
  The first line was empty and this one was interru
  E
  33
  ```